# How many screen sizes should be handled typically for a responsive website?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I am new to responsive web designing and CSS3 media queries. I am designing a website that will be accessed through browser on all kind of devices like cell phones, tabs, desktop.
I am using CSS3 media queries and in the process of creating css for my website. I want the font-size, the width of the div should vary as per device's screen width
How many screen sizes should be handled typically if I want my website to look fine on all type of devices. Is there a standard for it?
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you resize your browser window, it should simply look good on every possible size (resize your browser window and make sure you drag it through all the sizes for yourself: smallest to largest for your monitor.)

Then test this as well for different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a handy tool for this on www.quirktools.com/screenfly.
But remember it's a tool. It should look good on all sizes. No matter how you drag it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot of free responsive templates on the web that already do that, but if you want to build your own design from scratch, you should start with a full version of your site for desktop browsers, then add css styles for most common devices/sizes. 
Keep in mind that there are a lot of different resolutions a tablet or smartphone could have. 1080p, 720p, 800x600 etc. and a lot in-between.
Just do a quick search for a reference of responsive design device resolution.